# (rpy2) pandas2ri.ri2py(df) converting NA_integer_ to integer 1

Tags: python, r, na, rpy2

I am trying to import a SPSS file into python through rpy2 using the following code.

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri, r
filename = 'x.sav'
df = r('foreign::read.spss("%s", reencode = "cp1252", use.value.labels=TRUE, to.data.frame = TRUE)' % filename)
```

I have missing values inside my file that I would like to keep.
For example:

```
df[361]

#Returns
R object with classes: ('factor',) mapped to:
<FactorVector - Python:0x0000000011657CC8 / R:0x0000000012DAE738>
[NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, ..., NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_]

print(df[361])

#Returns
[1] <NA>              <NA>              <NA>              <NA>             

[2] <NA>              <NA>              <NA>              <NA>             

[3] <NA>              <NA>              <NA>              <NA>                        

[4] Agree (2)         Agree (2)         <NA>              <NA>             

[5] <NA>              <NA>              <NA>              <NA>             

5 Levels: Strongly Agree (1) Agree (2) ... Strongly Disagree (5)
```

However, when I perform a pandas2ri.ri2py conversion, it changes all NA_interger_ to integer value 1 and takes after the value label.

```
df = pandas2ri.ri2py(df)
df.iloc[:, 361]

#Returns
1      Strongly Agree (1)
2      Strongly Agree (1)
3      Strongly Agree (1)
4      Strongly Agree (1)
...
13     Agree (2)
14     Agree (2)
...
19     Strongly Agree (1)
20     Strongly Agree (1)
```

How can I stop prevent pandas2ri.ri2py() from automatically converting these NA_Integers_ ?